# How should I optimise my function with Google Apps Script when using simple triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timeout, dropdown

I am using Scripts to create a multi- select dropdown using onEdit as the function. The issue I have is that it was initially working perfectly & executing in 0.15s but has now started timing out after 30 seconds. I'm not sure how to adapt this as I don't know what the change is. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function MultiSelect(e) {
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (
    activeCell.getColumn() == 2 &&
    ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Waitlist'
  ) {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue('');
    } else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
      } else {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Script image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAWQE.png)

Comment: Is `MultiSelect` called by `onEdit`? If so please include your `onEdit` function.

Comment: @TheWizEd OP is probably using installed onEdit trigger. There's no other code in his image.

Comment: @TheMaster do we know that?  There is nothing obvious in the OP script that would cause any performance delay.  I was thinking his work process is `function onEdit(e) { some code; MultiSelect(e); some code; }` it may be the other onEdit code.

Comment: @TheWizEd We don't know that.  It's just a guess, because `function MultiSelect(e)` is line 1 in the image.

Comment: Yes, I was using an installed onEdit trigger. Sorry for not clarifying. Fixed via the answer from Cooper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function MultiSelect(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Waitlist') {
    if (!e.value) {
      e.range.setValue('');
    } else if (!e.oldValue) {
      e.range.setValue(e.value);
    } else {
      e.range.setValue(e.oldValue + ', ' + e.value);
    }
  }
}
```